# Story identification: 60s tv episode where a man tries to drive out of a town but always end up in it?

Tags: tv, episode-identification

I thought this was a Twilight Zone or Outer Limits, but after reviewiing the lists of episodes, it doesn't appear to be. I remember it as black and white.

Answer (score 6):

Could you be remembering the Twilight Zone episode [Stopover in a quiet town](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stopover_in_a_Quiet_Town)?  Involved a couple and it was a train not a car but the idea is the same.  Only one train out of town (Centerville) and it brought you right back to Centerville.  Episode is from Season 5 and is available for streaming from Netflix.

Comment: It's almost certainly this.  It's an episode people remember and talk about, but often can't place.

Answer (score 3):

This is almost certainly [The Prisoner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Prisoner).

It's a British spy series, where in the backstory a secret agent that quits under tense circumstances is kidnapped and taken to a strange town which acts as a prison of sorts, and subjected to bizarre and violent behavior. In his many escapes, he's chased by what looks to be a giant beach ball.

Comment: The Prisoner was offbeat enough that I would think the questioner would have remembered the 'weirdness' and commented on it.  Maybe not although the giant beach ball is a signature of the series and hard to forget.

Comment: _The Prisoner_ was in color, though.

Comment: @Tango Good point, but that really depended on what sort of television you had. Ah, the joys of analog video signals!