# Man tries to drive out of town, but keeps winding up at a diner outside of town

Tags: story-identification, tv

There was a TV episode of a man that cannot find his way into or as I remember out of a town. On returning to the town he stops at the same isolated diner over and over again. The diner is inside or outside the town limits. He is traveling alone in a car. And the road signs, probably at forks in the road, steer him in circles. I can’t locate the series or episode.

I recall seeing it between 1996 and 1999. I thought it was Outer Limits but as I said I can’t find it.

Comment: By the by, good on you for moving this to its own question. Hopefully, we can help you.

Comment: I should have added... you can accept answers by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Comment: i dont know why this reminded me of a twilight zone episode. but its not really what you are describing

Comment: There's a hinted sub-plot to this effect in the classic Twilight Zone "Nick of Time" episode (starring William Shatner (!)). It was also what I first thought of, but it's very much not it.

Comment: It's not the same as [this related question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/33469/59028) or [this other one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/177628/59028), is it?

Answer (score 9):

Could this be [Southbound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southbound_(2015_film)), an anthology of indie horror short films?

The first story seems to [match](http://www.28dayslateranalysis.com/2016/02/this-southbound-journey-has-only-one.html)  elements of your description;

> The anthology begins with "The Way Out and The Way In." Three more are quickly on there way. In this short two friends are chased by grim reaper like ghasts. Jack (Matt Bettinelli-Olpin) and Mitch (Chad Villella) cannot escape as all roads lead back to an isolated diner.

Comment: Southbound is good and close but as a clarification the episode I saw in the 90s involved one driver and a diner at night.

Comment: @JHuber - https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/177628/whats-the-name-of-that-tv-sci-fi-horror-series-with-a-truck-driver-who-cant-es

Answer (score 8):

I figured it out,  it was a  TV anthology movie called ESCAPES 1986

> An anthology of five tales of terror, each originally produced for video. The titles are "Something's Fishy," "Coffee Break," "Who's There," "Jonah's Dream," and "Think Twice."

Coffee Break
Young trucker is rocking out to hard rock/metal music and asks an old man for directions as he keeps looping through the town. He tells him if you slow down, enjoy the scenery and stop (at a Diner in the town) for a nice cup of coffee, he'll get out and find the highway. In the end, he goes into the diner where he's confronted by everyone and the old man forcing the pot of coffee towards him and he asks, "what do you people want from me?" After drinking the coffee, he becomes the town's newest resident and the sign changes the population count.

Comment: Good find! Sadly, odds are the querent is long gone, but take my upvote.

Comment: FWIW, [it's on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YIUNJekmhEI)

Comment: If accepted, it would be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/177628/whats-the-name-of-that-tv-sci-fi-horror-series-with-a-truck-driver-who-cant-es?noredirect=1&lq=1, which was accepted in a comment.

Comment: This also sounds very similar to a Stephen King short story "You Know They Got a Hell of a Band" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_Know_They_Got_a_Hell_of_a_Band