# Older black and white British horror film believed to be late 50s early 60s

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

Looking for older black and white British horror film believed to be late 50s early 60s where the characters try to escape and when they drive away the roads lead them back to the original location.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Are there any science fiction or fantasy elements in this movie?

Comment: One of these? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/225917/man-tries-to-drive-out-of-town-but-keeps-winding-up-at-a-diner-outside-of-town

Comment: What was at the original location? What were the characters trying to escape from?

Comment: Was a scene like that in "Night of the Demon", from 1957?

Comment: Possibly relevant tvtropes: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/UnnaturallyLoopingLocation

Answer (score 5):

This may be a partial remembering of [*Dead of Night*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_of_Night) (1946). Its circular plot was quite famous at the time and "inspired [British scientist] Fred Hoyle's steady state model of the universe".

The film begins:

> Walter Craig arrives at a country cottage in Kent

It ends:

> Craig then drives up to Foley's cottage in Kent as in the start of the film.